# Opposite faces in the net of a cuboid

Tags: geometry

[image: cuboid]

Given the net of a cuboid or a cube, how to find the couple of opposite faces ?

I have got the algorithm, and I would like some clarity about it.

Let $W,N,S,E$ the direction. Starting from one face, I can do the following movements :

- I have to stay on the net
- The first direction should be equal to the last direction
- $NN$ , $NEEEN$, $NEEEN$ are the unique possibilities ( modulo the labeling of the direction)
- The movements in between are allowed because we fold the net.

Comment: Is this net fixed once for all ?

Comment: Yes, given one net fixed (cuboid or cube), we want to find the opposite faces.